# PHPUnit can't find Phalcon's Callback validator (namespace issue)

Tags: php, phpunit, phalcon

I'm using Phalcon 3.0.3 and PHP `7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4` with PHPUnit 6.0.8. If I try to use `Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Callback` I'll always end up with those kind of errros:

`1) Test\ConfirmActivityTest::testConfirm
Error: Class 'Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Callback' not found`

So far the only way I found to solve this problem is to create a copy of that class in my codebase:

namespace Phapp\Validators;

```
/**
 * A workaround to fix the namespace problem of
 * Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Callback
 *
 */
class CallbackValidator extends \Phalcon\Validation\Validator
{

    /**
     * Executes the validation
     *
     * @param \Phalcon\Validation $validation
     * @param string $field
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validate(\Phalcon\Validation $validation, $field) {}

}
```

Is there any other workaround I could use to solve this problem? Is it a Phalcon bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback validator was added in 3.1.0. Docs were by mistake merged as i remember.

Comment: It was that. Good catch.